# php function for csv conversion w/ commas and other formatting characters

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export

I am downloading my data from MySQL to `.csv` format. I am having no problem using `mysql_real_escape_string()`, but this function removes any commas or formatting characters  that exist in my data.. So the `.csv` structure is maintained, but my grammatical characters (such as commas) are expectantly removed.

Comment: Are you calling mysql_real_escape_string() on export or when you are trying to import the csv file back into another database?

Comment: Clint, it was a recommendation I found to use mysql_real_escape_string() on the import. It actually worked in terms of csv format and removing the commas, but did not maintain the commas were they are in the original data.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_real_escape_string doesn't REMOVE data. It simply makes a string safe to insert into an SQL query. Standard rules for CSV is the enclose any string containing commas in double-quotes, so

```
This is my comma , containing string
```

becomes

```
"This is my comma, containing string"
```

in the CSV output. And any fields containing double-quotes should have the quotes doubled:

```
This is my "little" friend
```

becomes

```
This is my ""little"" friend
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclosing each field with double quotes helps.

A function to convert an array to CSV:

```
function arr2csv($twoDaray) {
   foreach($twoDarray as $k=>$v) {
      $row=implode('","',$v);
      echo '"'.$row.'"'.chr(10).chr(13);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by wrapping the entire string in quotes, then individually wrapping quotes and commas to maintain the formatting:

```
...
$csv_output .= "\"" . eregi_replace("\"", "\"\"", stripslashes($rowr[$j])) . "\",";
...
```

You'll note that I strangely applied stripslashes(). Unfortunately the script I am working on only works in php4, and so slashes are added by default settings of the .ini. So I just strip them out.

I'll also probably replace eregi_replace() with str_replace() as I believe it's deprecated.

Anyhow. The above solution works to remove commas and slashes and maintains them where